# Analytics and Gthsrvc Shares folders Permissions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, 2016

SharePoint Search Service has some Analytics and Gthsrvc Shares folders and it has below certain permissions  in Application Servers

[image]
For Some security regulations can I stop these Shared Folders in production APP servers?
because when any domain users access these shares appear (when entering the UNC path: \<SharePoint_servername> )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not stop these shared folders permissions in the production application servers.

Comment: Please can you share any Microsoft SharePoint documentations about these Search Service Share Folders